# AlertDialog keeps crashing

Tags: java, android, android-alertdialog

I am trying to implement a class that uses AlertDialog to display a confirmation dialog box (i.e. "Are you sure you want to do this?").
When I call it the first time, it works as expected. But if I try to call it again later, it crashes with `W/InputEventReceiver: Attempted to finish an input event but the input event receiver has already been disposed` error.

I can create individual AlertDialogs for each time I need to use a confirmation box, but that seems to be counter intuitive.
After doing some searching (2 days now) I haven't been able to find a working solution.
The class in question:

```
public class ConfirmDialog  {

    private boolean resultValue;
    private boolean result;
    private String title;
    private String message;
    private Context context;

    public ConfirmDialog(Context nContext, String nTitle, String nMessage) {
        context = nContext;
        title = nTitle;
        message = nMessage;
    }

    public boolean getResult()
    {
        final Handler handler = new Handler(new Handler.Callback() {
            @Override
            public boolean handleMessage(@NonNull Message msg) {
                throw new RuntimeException();
            }
        });

        AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
        alert.setTitle(title);
        alert.setMessage(message);
        alert.setPositiveButton("Yes", new
                DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
                {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id)
                    {
                        resultValue = true;
                        handler.sendMessage(handler.obtainMessage());
                    }
                });
        alert.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
        {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id)
            {
                resultValue = false;
                handler.sendMessage(handler.obtainMessage());
            }
        });
        alert.show();

        try{ Looper.loop();}

        catch(RuntimeException e){}

        return resultValue;
    }
}
```

Calling the class:

```
ConfirmDialog dialog = new ConfirmDialog(MainMenu.this, "Upload Batch", "Are you sure you want to upload this batch?");
                if(dialog.getResult() == false){
                    return false;
                }
                else {
                    //do something                
                }
```

I have inherited this project and didn't create this class. I also don't think I even need to use it, but if I can get it to work, it makes things a bit easier.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: are you starting another activity or something like that?

Comment: I supposed each time you are prompted with the confirmation dialog could be considered a new activity.